# Put values by alphabetical order in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, enums

I am making a little program which takes a list of pre-set values (they are implemented into the code of the application) which are sorted in alphabetical order. I have searched on the web for an answer, but no hope. The answers of the questions already asked were (I believe) for another version of the .Net Framework environment. So, here I am, trying to get a working answer.

My form with the enumeration and the dimming of the different values are like below:
(Sorry for long list, I just want to give all the possible code and environment values that you may need - and I don't know if you need the whole list of the Enum statement, so I rather give out the full list)

```
Public Class FrmMain

    Enum ModNames

        FS19_placeable_Shed
        FS19_Placeable_SD_hayShed
        FS19_baleStorage
        FS19_brickstonestilesheds
        FS19_MultiPurposeShed
        FS19_SteelBaleSheds
        FS19_Wooden_shelter
        FS19_Placeable_Easy_Shed_Small
        FS19_FrenchSheds
        FS19_Hangar_Metallique
        FS19_mashineryShed
        FS19_ThreeHalls
        FS19_Small_Shelter_Placeable
        FS19_LittleShelter
        FS19_HangarPlacable
        FS19_60X30_Equipment_Shed
        FS19_WoodenSheds
        FS_19_Easy_Shed_Pack
        FS19_WoolStorageShed
        FS19_VehicleShelter17
        FS19_vehicleShelter
        FS19_VehicleShed
        FS19_Long_Shed
        FS19_smallshed
        FS19_Shed5090Industry1
        FS19_Self_made_shed
        FS19_Placeable_SD_openShed
        FS19_Barrier_Pack
        FS19_corrugatedShed
        FS19_easyShedSet
        FS19_Placeable_Shelter
        FS19_machineShelterWithLight
        FS19_mfShedPack
        FS19_LS09ImplementShed
        FS19_BritishShed

    End Enum

    Private Sub FrmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ' Here is where I want to sort out the values from the enumeration above in alphabetical order.

    End Sub

End Class
```

As mentioned in the sample code above, I want to sort out the values from the enumeration when loading the form. I have a Text Box called `txtListOfMods`, and the *alphabetical-ordered* list will be outputted in that Text Box.
How can I do so?

Comment: `TextBox1.Lines = [Enum].GetNames(GetType(ModNames)).OrderBy(Function(en) en).ToArray()`. But, IMO, you need a List of class objects instead of a simple enum. The type of one of the properties  may be an enumerator, if one is needed.

Comment: Should the first underscore be there in `FS_19_Easy_Shed_Pack` or is that a mistake?

Comment: @jmcilhinney It is absolutely normal that it is like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Note: Answer comes from Jimi.

```
TextBox1.Lines = [Enum].GetNames(GetType(ModNames)).OrderBy(Function(en) en).ToArray()
```

But, IMO, you need a List of class objects instead of a simple Enum.
The type of one of the properties may be an enumerator, if one is needed.